# Inserting command line Arguments into vbscript

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript, cmd

Hey I have this code were I take two documents and read them. The two are `CurrentShares` and `ApprovedShares`. I compare these two and write the differences into a .txt file then I run a command to delete the shares, the command is `Net Share ShareName /DELETE`. That was the whiteList section.

The blacklist section is fairly the same, I take the previous **CurrentShares** and compare it to the **UnApprovedShares**. I then write the differences to a text file and delete the shares using the same command as before.

What I need is to seperate my script so when someone runs the script from the command line all they have to do is write `ShareDelete.vbs /Whitlist` or `ShareDelete.vbs /Blacklist` and depending on which one they type the command calls either the blacklist or whitelist verson. my code is

```
Option Explicit

Function DeleteThisShare(Share)
Dim objShell
   DeleteThisShare = "net share " & Share & " /DELETE"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    wscript.echo DeleteThisShare
    objShell.Run DeleteThisShare
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Whitelist
Wscript.echo "Calling cleanshares.vbs /whitelist.."

'Reads Approvedshare txt and makes the txt file into an array
Public objFSO 
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Dim objApprovedFile 
Set objApprovedFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\approvedshares.txt") 
Public strApprovedFile, strApprovedData, arrApprovedLines, ApprovedLineCount, strApprovedShares
CONST ForReading = 1
strApprovedFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\approvedshares.txt")
strApprovedData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Trim(strApprovedFile),ForReading).ReadAll
arrApprovedLines = Split(Trim(strApprovedData),vbCrLf)
wscript.echo strApprovedData
ApprovedLineCount = UBound(arrApprovedLines) + 1
strApprovedShares = strApprovedData
'wscript.echo "Approved share count : " &ApprovedLinecount

'Reads current shares txt and also makes that txt into an array
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objCurrentFile
Set objCurrentFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\currentshares.txt") 
Public strCurrentFile, strCurrentData, arrCurrentLines, CurrentLineCount, strCurrentShares, strNonApproved
strCurrentFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\currentshares.txt")
strCurrentData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Trim(strCurrentFile),ForReading).ReadAll
arrCurrentLines = Split(Trim(strCurrentData),vbCrLf)
CurrentLineCount = UBound(arrCurrentLines) + 1
'wscript.echo "current share count : " &CurrentLinecount

Do until objCurrentFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCurrentShares = objCurrentFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strApprovedShares, strCurrentShares) = 0 Then
    StrNonApproved = StrNonApproved & StrCurrentShares & vbCrLf
    End If

Loop
objApprovedFile.Close
objCurrentFile.Close

Wscript.echo "Current Shares Not approved: " & vbCrLf & strNonApproved
Set objWhiteFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\Shares_Not_Approved.txt")
Dim objWhiteFile : objWhiteFile.WriteLine strNonApproved '"The following shares are not listed as an approved share in the approvedshares.txt file.  Removing share from the PC: " & vbCrLf & strNonApproved

Dim notapprovedShares, notapprovedLines, strnotapprovedFile
strnotapprovedFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\Shares_Not_Approved.txt")
notapprovedLines = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strnotapprovedFile,ForReading).ReadAll
notapprovedLines = Split(notApprovedLines, vbCrLf)

Dim x, k, Line
k = uBound(notApprovedLines)

For x = 0 To k
    Line = Trim(notApprovedLines(x))
    If Len(Line) > 0 then
        DeleteThisShare(Line)
    End If
Next


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Blacklist
'Wscript.echo "Calling cleanshares.vbs /Blacklist.."

Function DeleteThisShare(Share)
Dim objShell
   DeleteThisShare = "net share " & Share & " /DELETE"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    wscript.echo DeleteThisShare
    objShell.Run DeleteThisShare
End Function


Set objCurrentFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\currentshares.txt")

'Reads UnApprovedShares and makes txt file into an array
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strUnApprovedFile, strUnApprovedData, arrUnApprovedLines, UnApprovedLineCount, strUnApprovedShares, strNonUnapprovedShares
strUnApprovedFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\unapprovedshares.txt")
strUnApprovedData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Trim(strUnApprovedFile),ForReading).ReadAll
arrUnApprovedLines = Split(Trim(strUnApprovedData),vbCrLf)
UnApprovedLineCount = UBound(arrUnApprovedLines) + 1
strUnApprovedShares = strUnApprovedData
'wscript.echo "Unapproved Share Count: " & UnApprovedLineCount
strCurrentFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\currentshares.txt")

Do until objCurrentFile.AtEndOfStream
     StrCurrentShares = objCurrentFile.Readline
 If InStr(strUnApprovedShares, strCurrentShares) = 0 Then
StrNonUnapprovedShares = StrNonUnapprovedShares & strCurrentShares & vbCrLf
 End If
Loop

Wscript.echo "Current shares Not UnApproved: " & vbcrLf & StrNonUnapprovedShares
Dim objBlackFile : Set objBlackFile = ObjFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\Shares_Not_Unapproved.txt")
objBlackFile.WriteLine StrNonUnapprovedShares

Dim notUnapprovedShares, notUnapprovedLines, strnotUnapprovedFile
strnotUnapprovedFile = ("C:\Users\a352592\Desktop\Abdullahi\Remove Shares Utility\Shares_Not_Unapproved.txt")
notUnapprovedLines = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strnotUnapprovedFile,ForReading).ReadAll
notUnapprovedLines = Split(notUnapprovedLines, vbCrLf)

Dim y, j, Line2
j = uBound(notUnapprovedLines)

For y = 0 to j
    Line2 = Trim(notUnapprovedLines(y))
    If len(Line2) > 0 Then
        DeleteThisShare(Line2)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A skeleton for dealing with named arguments:

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Quit Main()

Function Main()
  Main = 1

  Dim oWAN : Set oWAN = WScript.Arguments.Named
  Select Case True
    Case 1 <> oWAN.Count
      WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript demoargs.vbs /Whitelist OR /Blacklist"
    Case oWAN.Exists("Whitelist")
      WScript.Echo "doing Whitelist stuff"
      Main = 0
    Case oWAN.Exists("Blacklist")
      WScript.Echo "doing Blacklist stuff"
      Main = 0
  End Select
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript demoarg.vbs
Usage: cscript demoargs.vbs /Whitelist OR /Blacklist

cscript demoarg.vbs /Whitelist
doing Whitelist stuff

cscript demoarg.vbs /Blacklist
doing Blacklist stuff

cscript demoarg.vbs /Blacklist /Whitelist
Usage: cscript demoargs.vbs /Whitelist OR /Blacklist
```

See

1. [Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
2. [Named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6y04sbb%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
3. [Unnamed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah2hawwc%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)